# Netplan Configuration Isssue: Unable to obtain ip address for ethernet configured with dhcp4

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, dhcp, netplan

### Goal:

Determine why configuring an interface with only dhcp4 fails.

### Setup

I am working on configuring netplan for a Virtualbox VM.
The VM has 1 bridged adapter connected to my machines wlo1 and 2 internal adapters both connected to their own internal network (ie they are not connected to anything)
the adapters correspond to interfaces enp0s3 enp0s8 and enp0s9 respectively.

The default configuration for netplan is

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

### Problem

The default configuration works correctly. enp0s3 successfully gets an ip from my home router via dhcp.
The output of ip route shows a default route of 192.168.1.1

However, when I change the config to this

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
```

The interface fails to connect to the internet.
I cannot ping google.com
I cannot navigate to any pages via fire fox.
In journalctl Network manager spits out this log

```
<info>  [1701108834.0160] device (enp0s3): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Which prompted me to try and force netplan to get an ip4 address with the following command
`nmcli connection modify enp0s3 ipv4.method auto && nmcli connection up enp0s3`

And this command returned the following error

```
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.) 
Hint: use ‘journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=(long string) + NM_DEVICE=enp0s3’ to get more details
```

It is also worth noting that I have been able to get the second config in this question to work at the library which has a different network configuration. My Host machine is running Ubuntu 23.04 and the VM is running Ubuntu 22.04.

#### Edit:

I was able to get the connection to work again by setting dhcp6 to true in the netplan config (see below). Removing this field and applying the config brings back the original networking issue. My home network uses charter spectrum. My main question now is why is this required? Is this required?

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

Let me know if any more information would be helpful.

#### Edit:

Still interested in determining what might be causing this. Interested in if anybody has experience working with charter spectrum rented routers and possible issues that could cause this.